# How to create ClientContext in .asmx web service called from AJAX

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, ajax, asmx

i am developing Sharepoint online on-premise app. Almost all my logic and SP objects manipulation is in the c# codebehind(not JS), but now i need to call my already implemented method from js. I created .asmx and called it via jquery AJAX. The service is hit with all needed parameters, but i cannot create the ClientContext object so i can actually run the method i need. What should i do to have the context created?

JS

```
$("#approveYesBtn").click(function () {
    var taskId = $("#<%= selectedTaskHf.ClientID%>").val();
    var note = $("#<%= noteApproveTb.ClientID%>").val();
    var parameters = '{"taskIdStr":"' + taskId + '", "note":"' + note + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/DocumentApproval.asmx/ApproveTask",
        data: parameters,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",                        
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
                        documentApproveModal.close();
                        alert('task approved');
                    },
                    error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
                        documentApproveModal.close();
                        alert('error');
                    }
    });
});
```

.asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public void ApproveTask(string taskIdStr, string note)
{
    //always null
    var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

    using (var context = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPAppWeb())
    {      
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to generate the client context for the user who called the service or can you afford to  create the clientcontext for  a service account?

Comment: I need the context to be app context(app web, not host web) in order to access lists that are part of the app. I am not sure about your question, i guess i need it for the user but not sure what the difference would be. The code creating context i provided is how i usually create the context anywhere in the code, when not in .asmx service.

Comment: Okay what i wanted to know is should the code run under the credentials of the logged in user in SharePoint who makes a call to webservice or can it run under the credentials of any service account ?

Comment: I think it should run under the credentials of the app itself or credentials of the user using the app.

Comment: As long as i know i should just add some parameters to the header of the ajax request call in order to make it work, but i am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code.
Pass the site url as a parameter to your JSON call

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Url);
 string appOnlyAccessToken = TokenHelper.GetS2SAccessTokenWithWindowsIdentity(uri, null);
ClientContext ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(uri.ToString(), appOnlyAccessToken);
```